# Using super in overriden initialize

Tags: ruby, super

Why I not get 'init' string ?

```rb
class Dwa
  attr_reader :nazwa

  def initialize()
    puts 'init'
    @nazwa = "dwa"
  end
end

class Dwa #open this same object definition
  def initialize()
    super #or super()
    @nazwa = "trzy"
  end
end

d = Dwa.new
puts "#{d.nazwa}"
```

I open object again and redefine `initialize`.

When I run code with non-modified class I print `init` and `dwa`

How to modify `initialize` and still run `puts 'init'`

I expect:

```
$ run.rb
init
trzy
```

Comment: Not sure what you are actually going for here but technically you can use [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend) to facilitate this functionality.

Comment: how modyfy initialize() function and not lost prev code?

Comment: PSA: Empty argument lists can and should be omitted in Ruby in most cases, at least according to most style guides, as in `def initialize`

Comment: From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Overriding): _"When Ruby encounters the `def` keyword, it doesn’t consider it an error if the method already exists: it simply redefines it."_ i.e. the existing methods gets replaced.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is that re-opening `Dwa` and re-defining `initialize` will **replace** the old `initialize`. Since `super` only works to reference to the superclass it is useless in this scenario.

To call the old behaviour, you'll have to store the old `initialize` method somewhere and call it from the new definition. One way to do this would be to use [`instance_method`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/module#method-i-instance_method) to grab and store the `UnboundMethod` inside a variable. Then call it (using [`bind_call`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/unboundmethod#method-i-bind_call)) from the re-definition of `initialize`.

```rb
# re-opening Dwa class
class Dwa
  old_initialize = instance_method(:initialize)

  define_method :initialize do
    old_initialize.bind_call(self)
    @nazwa = "trzy"
  end
end
```

The reason we use [`define_method :initialize`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/module#method-i-define_method) here, instead of `def initialize`, is because of the context switch. Using `define_method :initialize` with a block allows us to access the outer `old_initialize` variable, which is not possible with `def initialize`.

---

Alternatively you could change the class structure/hierarchy and define a new class using `Dwa` as its superclass instead.

```rb
class NewDwa < Dwa
  def initialize
    super
    @nazwa = "trzy"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why I not get 'init' string ?

The superclass of `Doe` is `Object`. `Object#initialize` doesn't print anything, therefore you don't get any printout.

> How modyfy initialize and still run puts 'init'

```ruby
def initialize
  print 'init'
  @nazwa = "trzy"
end
```

Comment: I reopen prev definition, this is not Object but Dwa

Comment: `super` resends the message with method lookup starting at the superclass. The superclass of `Doe` is `Object`, which is the default superclass if you don't specify a superclass explicitly.

Comment: but code is more complicated and I need using prev code, not rewrite code himself

Comment: In Ruby the vehicle for code reuse is inheritance.

Comment: if You modyfy code: class Jeden; end and add class Dwa < Jeden This not working too. You wrote prev code is Jeden not Object.

Comment: inheritance ok ;) but this code working if I not use initialize

Comment: "You wrote prev code is Jeden not Object" – No, I did not.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to override this method, why don't override it fully and explicitly?

Probably it's the best option

But if you still want some hacks, you can use alias

```rb
# original class
class Dwa
  attr_reader :nazwa

  def initialize
   puts 'init'
   @nazwa = "dwa"
  end
end
```

```rb
# overriden class
class Dwa
  alias_method :original_initialize, :initialize

  def initialize
   original_initialize
   @nazwa = "trzy"
  end
end
```

```rb
d = Dwa.new
# will print init

puts d.nazwa
# will print trzy
```

Comment: _"why don't override it fully and explicitly?"_ – what do you mean by that? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Stefan I mean to write new method like in Jörg's answer

Comment: Oh I see. For a less hacky way you could put it into a module and `prepend` it into the class. (IIRC, not at the computer right now)